# Print message in expandable macro

Tags: expansion

Is it possible to print a message like `\message{…}` in an expandable macro for debugging purposes? I tried to create expandable functions with `\message{}`, but I can't plug them into siunit `\num{…}` that expects an expanded string.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{
  \message{Foo}%
  42%
}

\num{\foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only in LuaTeX. If errors are fine, you can also use those to expandably print to the console (works in all engines, e.g., L3's `\msg_expandable_error:nn` or `expkv`'s `\ekverr`).

Comment: Alternatively, for debugging, consider either `\tracing...` or the `unravel` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In luatex you can print from Lua eg

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{%
  \directlua{print('Foo')}%
  42%
}

\num{\foo}

\end{document}
```

Or use the `texio` module functions if you want to write to the log as well as the terminal.

Otherwise, you can use (for example) gobble and then turn on tracing):

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\MESSAGE#1{}
\begin{document}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{%
  \MESSAGE{Foo}%
  42%
}

\tracingmacros=1
\tracingonline=1
\num{\foo}
\tracingnone

\end{document}
```

run with

`pdflatex file | grep -A2 'MESSAGE #1'`

produces terminal output

```
\MESSAGE #1->
#1<-Foo
```

Comment: Thanks, too bad we can't do that in other engines as well.